# How to convert C# DateTime to MySQL timestamp table column

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to update a table element of type timestamp called dtprint with the current time (the original value is NULL). The code that I am using is as follows:

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Connection_String");
con.Open();
MySqlCommand _cmd = con.CreateCommand();

string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

_cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE requests SET dtprint = " + dt + " WHERE idPerson = " + _personID[index];

_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

The exception I keep getting is: Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '14:03:23 WHERE idPerson = 45' at line 1.

The only thing I can think of is that the Database isn't recognizing the time as a timestamp, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the types of `dtprint` and `idPerson` columns? And you should always use parameterized queries. This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks. If your `dtprint` is a `timestamp`, you should add it a `DateTime`, not `string`.

Comment: dtprint is of type timestamp, and idPerson is of type int

Comment: put single quotes around your date string.  `'" + dt + "'`

Comment: do you have access to convert the UPDATE command to a stored procedure..? if so do that..also I would recommend converting the UPDATE statement to utilize Parameterized query and wrap the `_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` around a try{}catch(SqlException sqlEx{show the sqlEx.Message here} so that you can capture the SQLException

Answer (score 2):

Since `dt` is a `string` and your `dtprint` is `timestamp`, you need to use single quotes when you try to insert it. Like;

```
"UPDATE requests SET dtprint = '" + dt + "' WHERE
```

### But don't use this way.

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections and objects.

```
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using(MySqlCommand _cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    _cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE requests SET dtprint = @dtprint
                         WHERE idPerson = @id";
    _cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtprint", MySqlType.TimeStamp).Value = dt; 
    _cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlType.Int).Value = _personID[index];
     con.Open();
    _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();      
}
```